# A simple string manipulation produces differing results across Linux versions - Why?

Tags: c

The following code produces different results when run on different OS, in particular under Fedora 14/CentOS 6.6 the final displayed value is miin, under Fedora 9/17 and CentOS 6.2 it is main.

While I am sure there are numerous ways for achieving the final goal of 'main', this code is deep inside a program that is failing and this is the test case that uses the internal function logic. My question is why is this code not working between across different versions of Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main () 
{ 
  char mival[30]="/main.html"; 
  char *p; 
  char *newval; 

printf ("mival: %s\n",mival); 

    p = strchr(mival,'\0'); 

    while(*p != '/' && *p != '.') 
        --p; 

    if (*p == '.') 
        { 
        *p = '\0'; 
        while(*p != '/') 
            --p; 
        } 
    *p = '\0';         
    newval = p+1; 

    strcpy(mival, newval); 


  printf ("mival: %s\n",mival);   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger on the platforms where it doesn't work?

Comment: You probably want `strncpy`, because that is only copies the number of characters you want; also memmove is a good idea.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a workaround which might work for you if you are unable to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strcpy()` function causes *undefined behaviour* when the string you are copying overlaps the destination. In such cases, you need to use `memmove()`.

If you are unable to rewrite the function, there's a quick fix that might be usable: Duplicating the string would make the `strcpy()` non-overlapping:

```
char mival[30]="/main.html";
char mival2[60];
strcpy (mival2, mival);
strcat (mival2, mival);
/* Operatate on mival2 */
```

Otherwise, I would strongly suggest that you rewrite the broken function. This is my suggestion (briefly tested):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int main () 
{ 
  char mival[30]="/main.html"; 
  size_t dot, start, len;

  printf ("mival: %s\n",mival); 

  len = strlen (mival);
  dot = len;
  start = 0;

  do {
    if (mival[len] == '.') {
      dot = len;
    } else if (mival[len] == '/') {
      start = len+1;
      break;
    }
  } while (len--);

  memmove (mival, mival+start, dot-start);
  mival[dot-start] = 0;

  printf ("mival: %s\n",mival);   
  return 0;
}
```

Note that this code finds the *first* dot after the last slash (which is what I would want), while your code finds the *last* dot.

You could also use `strrchr()` to find the rightmost slash, followed by `strchr()` to find the first dot after the slash, but I think this approach would give me more headaches.

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't really use `memmove()` or `strcpy()` I would just return the pointer or something but that since we dont know the usecase.

Comment: Software vendor accepted that the problem was their code and provided a patch